# CMake can't find Findglfw3.cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, glfw

I am trying to transition to VScode and CMake (on Windows 11 using MSVC) and refactoring a project that was previously working with Visual Studio. I have successfully linked GLEW but can not seem to get GLFW to work. I have the binaries downloaded directly from the glfw site.

My relevant project layout is:
Project Folder:

```
|main.cpp
|Dependencies folder
    |_GLEW (working)
    |_GLFW (not working)
        |docs
        |include
            |GLFW
                glfw3.h
                glfw3native.h
```

My relevant CMakeLists.txt is:

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
add_executable(YEngine main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(YEngine GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(YEngine glfw)
```

I receive the error:

```
[cmake]   By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
[cmake]   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
[cmake]   CMake did not find one.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" with any of
[cmake]   the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     glfw3Config.cmake
[cmake]     glfw3-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
[cmake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
[cmake]   installed.
```

I attempted to add

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/XProject/Dependencies/_GLFW")
```

as well as

```
set(glfw3_DIR "D:/XProject/Dependencies/_GLFW/")
```

however neither fixed the issue, and I would guess should not be necessary as they were not required for GLEW to work. I also tried going up and down levels in the directories for the paths that are above, but CMake can still not seem to find it.

I would prefer to avoid going back to Visual Studio if possible, and I'd prefer to use the prebuilt binaries if possible as well.

Comment: As you could read from the error message, using `find_package(glfw3)` requires existence of one of 3 files: `Findglfw3.cmake`, `glfw3Config.cmake` or `glfw3-config.cmake`. Since your shipped GLFW lacks for these files, the approach with `find_package` cannot be used. But you could directly use commands `target_link_libraries`, `target_include_directories` and pass them appropriate GLFW paths.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought include_directories was deprecated since find_package was introduced, but those commands worked perfectly...for main.cpp. Now I can't get glfw to open with other headers. Do you have any sources you'd recommend for learning more about CMake? I know that it's outside the scope of the question here, but I just want to avoid constantly bothering StackOverflow with inane questions.

Comment: "Do you have any sources you'd recommend for learning more about CMake?" - CMake documentation has a [nice tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html), which describes many features (which are up-to-date).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Even when following the tutorial exactly though, it already fails to run properly on my machine using the source code provided for the first tutorial. I can't seem to get anything to work with this other than a basic "Hello World" style program with no C++ required version and no external packages needed. It's just not for me I guess. I appreciate the attempt to help all the same.